Detect hidden failures in Scala Chimney
If a type A has field x and field B has everything A has except field x?  For example:
case class A(a: Int, b: String, x: Boolean)
case class B(a: Int, b: String)

val a = A(1, "test", true)

a.transformInto[B] will work and will return in B(1, "test") and will silently throw away the Boolean x.  This is a silent failure that I would like to detect and log.
Has anyone found a way to do this natively with Chimney conversions?  Or do we have to validate the Source and Target types manually by looking at the field names/count?
Thanks

What's the problem background? Can you give a minimum example code?  You declare class rather than case class which would make trouble in accessing member inside. In Chimney, transformation works between case classes, or classes with public getters.

It's a feature request, not yet implemented - https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney/issues/248 . AFAIK this makes more sense in Java where MapStruct is used to document mappings, less so in Scala where you can generate a conversion recursively and check it with an integration test. You can preview the result with https://chimney.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting/#debugging-macros . If user had to suppress unused fields by default, the code of DSL would be longer than the code it generates which defeast the purpose of the library (removing boilerplate).

Also: Chimney defines "failure" (in compile time) as the inability to match every target's constructor argument (or setter) with some source value, and every source's subtypes with some target value. Recursively. Inputs fields aren't even checked for matches since there are: vals from constructor's argument list, vals from body, nullary defs, getters, all of the above but inherited... looking only at case class fields and checking if they are all used sounds "obvious" only in the most basic cases that I virtually never had.

Problem is when you have two types Source and Target each from different projects with a gateway where you are converting from one to the other.  If Target is smaller than Source the delta will be thrown out unless we add that field in both projects.  This is fine... a day in the life of an engineer...
But it would be great to be able to detect it and log a warning at the very least.

Another way to think about it is: Isomorphic transformation, being able to convert back and forth.  Even though I wouldn’t do that, I want to make sure it could, sort of...

Iso transformers are a thing on their own and a separate use case. I don't argue that such check wouldn't be useful - one volunteer is working on it ATM - but in an unpaid and (currently, mostly) one man project where each new "small" feature takes a several days to make sure that it plays nice with existing features I have to prioritize to decide what get the little time I have. The last "it would be nice" feature took me a month... and it's used by less than 1% of Chimney users.

I appreciate what you do.  Love the library.  Maybe I can help with building in my dwindling free time.

Thanks! Right now someone is working on a PR to implement field checking policies, maybe you look at the PR?
